# Lightbox2 Image Repeats twice when used with TinyCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict, lightbox2, tiny-carousel

I am currently having problems with Lightbox2 and TinyCarousel working together!

When i add the lightbox link onto an image within the carousel it shows 2 of that image within the lightbox.

I read a similar situation with bxSlider and the solution was to change the infinite variable to false - i have tried this within tiny carousel but it does not work.

You can see the problem here: http://www.elementintermedia.com/newsite/
Click on the first image in the Slider to start the lightbox and it displays that linked image twice within the lightbox. This is the only lightbox link on the current page also.

I know it's tiny carousel casuing the problem as if i remove that plugin the lightbox works correctly and olny shows the image once

Can anyone please help?? Thanks

Comment: I would try combining a different carousel with your lightbox or vice versa. It is really hard to find the problem with such plugins. Some of them are thousands of lines of codes and writing it yourself is also a lot of work. I am sure there are plenty of similar carousels out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightbox2 2.7.1 and the [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) carousel work well together

for the buttons :

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn" href="#scroller" data-slide="prev">previous</a>
    <a class="btn" href="#scroller" data-slide="next">next</a>
</div>
```

And the carousel :

```
<div id="scroller" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            your content here
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            your content here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I didn't use it exactly like you (1 image per step), but I'm sure you can find a lot of usage examples on the web.